# Get An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host when connecting to MT4

Tags: c#, mt4

I am using [mtapi](https://mtapi.tech/) in order to connect to mt4 in order to get data and create orders using the below code.

```
QuoteClient qc = new QuoteClient(clientId, "password", "IP", 443);
qc.Connect();
var h = qc.DownloadQuoteHistory("EURUSD", Timeframe.M5, DateTime.Now, 6);
qc.Disconnect();
```

The application works really well for around 1 month, I am getting the below error from time to time on the server where the application is deployed. Sometimes the application works fine and sometimes getting the below error.

```
Exception Type: TradingAPI.MT4Server.ConnectException
Message: Disconneted: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

At the same time if I try to connect from my local machine, it connects without any error.

I am not sure what is exactly happening, is it possible that there is too much requests and they are blocking me.